# while there is no line 16 but still giving error "line 16 : syntax error: unexpected end of line"

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting, syntax-error

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

if [[ $a -gt $b && $a -gt $c ]]
then
echo "A is the greater number"
if [[ $b -gt $a && $b -gt $c ]]
then
echo "B is the greater number"
else
echo "C is the greate number"
fi
```

I tried doing dos2unix formatting, adding another 'fi' but still code throwing same error

---

EDIT by Ed Morton: here's your code with common indenting:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

if [[ $a -gt $b && $a -gt $c ]]
then
    echo "A is the greater number"
    if [[ $b -gt $a && $b -gt $c ]]
    then
        echo "B is the greater number"
    else
        echo "C is the greate number"
    fi
```

I expect the problem is no longer a mystery if you format your code that way.

Comment: (You say you added a second `fi`, but _where_ you add it matters; if you just put it on the end that wouldn't fix anything at all -- though it would be better to only have one `if` and thus only need one `fi` regardless)

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/ is your friend for detecting this class of problem without needing to get humans involved

Comment: If you indent your code to follow the control constructs you use (e.g. go forward at every `if`, `while`, body and backward at every `fi`, `done`) then you won't have problems like this or, if you do, it'll be immediately obvious to you why.

Answer (score 3):

You have two `if` statements but only one `fi`. Try using `elif` for your second case instead:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30

if [[ $a -gt $b && $a -gt $c ]]; then
    echo "A is the greater number"
elif [[ $b -gt $a && $b -gt $c ]]; then
    echo "B is the greater number"
else
    echo "C is the greater number"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

It a better option to split test logic operators outside of brackets.

Here is an example of another implementation of your code:

```bash
a=10
b=20
c=30

if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ] && [ "$a" -gt "$c" ]; then
  gtst='A'
elif [ "$b" -gt "$a" ] && [ "$b" -gt "$c" ]; then
  gtst='B'
else
  gtst='C'
fi
printf '%s is the greatest number.\n' "$gtst"
```

Comment: In what respect do you consider this better? IMO, if we go for readability, a bitter solution would be i.e. `if (( a>b && a>c )); then`.

Comment: @user1934428 It's better practice when using `[`, certainly, since `-a` and `-o` are deprecated there. While that doesn't strictly apply to `[[`, encouraging users to develop habits that will serve them well when they _do_ need to write code for baseline POSIX is not unreasonable (though I personally do prefer arithmetic syntax as you demonstrate in the comment above)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This↑ I also find the arithmetic syntax easier but I learned to avoid Bash-only features, unless it has no baseline POSIX replacement. Bash arrays, Regex and `< <(cmd group)` input streams are very convenient and hard to implement if not possible with POSIX. Other than those, I write test conditions using POSIX. I even prefer `case $var in *pattern*)` over `if [[ $var == *pattern* ]]`. There is no functional difference here worth trading wider shell compatibility. Bash syntactic shugar is usually not much worth its trade-offs.

Comment: Thank you,  for taking time to answer my question and ensuring better readability of code,